# Should Swagger documentation only contain @Controller layer?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I need to use Swagger for my project and as I knew it should only contain endpoints in the project.
I use Spring Boot and springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui Swagger library, but it not only contains @Controller layer but @Service and @Entity too. I'm confused, is that normal? Why are they generated?
[image: My Swagger page]

Comment: Can you share code, or github link? I believe you might have annoted it somewhere it could be causing the issue.

Comment: It was generated by springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui library, I didn't make any other configurations.